# Best way to uniquely identify a server in VPS environment?

Tags: vps

We have two servers, live and fallback, both hosted in a VPS environment (Linode and MediaTemple, although this could change at any moment). I want them to have an identical set of shell scripts but of course, some of the shell scripts might need to do slightly different things depending on which server they are on.

In this context, what is the best way to identify which server the script is being run on? Again, this is a VPS environment so we have no control over IPs, hardware, and so on.

I understand that there may not be a "perfect" answer so any good-enough solution or best practice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a "best practice", but this works for me. Have a lookaside list in a text file of "live servers" and "fallback servers" with hostnames. Use that list to determine which type of server it is, then take the appropriate action. Alternately, assume "live" unless it's in the lookaside file, in which case it's "fallback" (or vice-versa). Or toch a file in `/etc/` telling you which it is (e.g. `/etc/live` or `/etc/fallback`). There are literally an infinite number of possibilities, ultimately the one you go with will be based on which one you 1) understand most and 2) are most comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you John. I probably need to clarify that I would like advice on how to "identify" a server rather than specify which server it is myself (via text files or other similar means as you suggested).

Comment: Identification is either by lookaside table like I mentioned or by some method unique to the application. The closest you'll get from an OS perspective is a hostname (or similar), which doesn't help you in identifying "live" from "fallback" without a very strict naming protocol.

Comment: For only two servers, using hostname or checking for the existence of a unique file on each host would be fine IMO.